# Docker python-alpine 3.9 missing ibtbb

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, build, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install libtbb library on python alpine3.9 ( the documentation clearly says, that it is available: [url](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/libtbb) ), but whenever I do try to build the image, i receive following error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libtbb (missing):
    required by: world[libtbb]
```

Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9
# Let the container know that there is no TTY
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Metapackage that pulls in the most essential packages used to build new packages

# Install packages
RUN apk update \
    && apk add g++ \
    libc6-compat \
    make \
    build-base \
    openblas-dev \
    unzip \
    cmake \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    libstdc++  \
    libxml2 \
    zip \
    libtbb  \
    lua5.2 \
    wget \
    cmake clang clang-dev make gcc g++ libc-dev linux-headers \
    boost-dev \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc g++ python3-dev musl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `--no-cache` and `add` after `apk update` in the same command without `&&`  so `apk update` will affect `add` command and will update repository for subsequent packages.

`--update` flag fetches the current package index before adding the package

`--no-cache` option for apk. It allows users to install packages with an index that is updated and used on-the-fly and not cached locally:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9
# Let the container know that there is no TTY
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Metapackage that pulls in the most essential packages used to build new packages

# Install packages
RUN apk update --no-cache add \
    g++ \
    libc6-compat \
    make \
    build-base \
    openblas-dev \
    unzip \
    cmake \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    libstdc++  \
    libxml2 \
    zip \
    libtbb  \
    lua5.2 \
    wget \
    cmake clang clang-dev make gcc g++ libc-dev linux-headers \
    boost-dev \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc g++ python3-dev musl-dev
```

In my experience, this applies to the current command so may thats the reason but I did not find such thing in the documentation but `apk` help show this.

```
usage: apk COMMAND [-h|--help] [-p|--root DIR] [-X|--repository REPO] [-q|--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [-i|--interactive] [-V|--version] [-f|--force]
           [--force-binary-stdout] [--force-broken-world] [--force-non-repository] [--force-old-apk] [--force-overwrite] [--force-refresh] [-U|--update-cache]
           [--progress] [--progress-fd FD] [--no-progress] [--purge] [--allow-untrusted] [--wait TIME] [--keys-dir KEYSDIR] [--repositories-file REPOFILE]
           [--no-network] [--no-cache] [--cache-dir CACHEDIR] [--arch ARCH] [--print-arch] [ARGS]...
```